# How to profile a web application with Attach to a Net 4 Process option using ANTS Profiler?

Tags: web-applications, red-gate-ants

Can anyone tell me how to use the Attach to a Net 4 process option in ANTS Profiler for a web application? I can see it is available for console application(.exe) but not for web applciation. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select "Attach to a .NET 4 process", ANTS shows a list of all the .NET 4 processes which are running. w3wp needs to actually be running to appear in this list, which it won't be if you haven't accessed the website recently. Try requesting the site in any browser, then in ANTS, hit Refresh to look again at the list of processes - hopefully w3wp will have appeared.